# isSelected() Checkbox error

Tags: java, eclipse, checkbox

I'm making some kind of calculating program where user can input the number of drinks that they want to order and a button will calculate the amount of money they need to pay. If they checked the delivery box, there will be an addition of $30 for delivery cost. i'm using isSelected to check if they box if ticked or not but it's not working. the error that i get is "the method isSelected() is undefined for the type Checkbox".

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class hwextend{

static Frame frm = new Frame("Action Event");
static Checkbox ckb1 = new Checkbox("Delivery");
static Button btn = new Button("Calculate");
static TextField textfield1 = new TextField();
static TextField textfield2 = new TextField();
static TextField textfield3 = new TextField();
static TextField textfield4 = new TextField();
static TextField textfield5 = new TextField();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout (7,3);
    btn.addActionListener(new ActListener());
    frm.setLayout(grid);
    frm.setSize(400,200);
    frm.setBackground(Color.pink);


    Label lab1 = new Label ("Tea Series");
    Font font1 = new Font(null,Font.BOLD,12);
    lab1.setFont(font1);
    frm.add(lab1);
    frm.add(new Label(""));
    frm.add(new Label(""));


    frm.add(new Label("Black Tea"));
    frm.add(new Label("$70"));
    frm.add(textfield1);


    frm.add(new Label("Green Tea"));
    frm.add(new Label("$70"));
    frm.add(textfield2);

    Label lab2 = new Label ("Special Flavor Series");
    lab2.setFont(font1);
    frm.add(lab2);
    frm.add(new Label(""));
    frm.add(new Label(""));


    frm.add(new Label("Alpine Tea"));
    frm.add(new Label("$80"));
    frm.add(textfield3);


    frm.add(new Label("Stewed Oolong Tea"));
    frm.add(new Label("$80"));
    frm.add(textfield4);


    frm.add(btn);
    frm.add(ckb1);


    frm.add(textfield5);
    frm.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    { 
          public void windowClosing (WindowEvent Event) {
          System.exit (0);
         } 
        } 
        );


    frm.setVisible(true);
}


static class ActListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText().toString());
        int c = Integer.parseInt(textfield3.getText().toString());
        int d = Integer.parseInt(textfield4.getText().toString());

        if (ckb1).isSelected()){
            textfield5.setText(String.valueOf((a+b)*70+(c+b)*80)+30);
        }
        else {
        textfield5.setText(String.valueOf((a+b)*70+(c+b)*80));
        }
            }


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use ckb1.getState() instead of ckb1.isselected()

Please find the updated code working fine

```
static Frame frm = new Frame("Action Event");
static Checkbox ckb1 = new Checkbox("Delivery");
static Button btn = new Button("Calculate");
static TextField textfield1 = new TextField();
static TextField textfield2 = new TextField();
static TextField textfield3 = new TextField();
static TextField textfield4 = new TextField();
static TextField textfield5 = new TextField();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout (7,3);
    btn.addActionListener(new ActListener());
    frm.setLayout(grid);
    frm.setSize(400,200);
    frm.setBackground(Color.pink);


    Label lab1 = new Label ("Tea Series");
    Font font1 = new Font(null,Font.BOLD,12);
    lab1.setFont(font1);
    frm.add(lab1);
    frm.add(new Label(""));
    frm.add(new Label(""));


    frm.add(new Label("Black Tea"));
    frm.add(new Label("$70"));
    frm.add(textfield1);


    frm.add(new Label("Green Tea"));
    frm.add(new Label("$70"));
    frm.add(textfield2);

    Label lab2 = new Label ("Special Flavor Series");
    lab2.setFont(font1);
    frm.add(lab2);
    frm.add(new Label(""));
    frm.add(new Label(""));


    frm.add(new Label("Alpine Tea"));
    frm.add(new Label("$80"));
    frm.add(textfield3);


    frm.add(new Label("Stewed Oolong Tea"));
    frm.add(new Label("$80"));
    frm.add(textfield4);


    frm.add(btn);
    frm.add(ckb1);


    frm.add(textfield5);
    frm.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    { 
          public void windowClosing (WindowEvent Event) {
          System.exit (0);
         } 
        } 
        );


    frm.setVisible(true);
}


static class ActListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(textfield1.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(textfield2.getText().toString());
        int c = Integer.parseInt(textfield3.getText().toString());
        int d = Integer.parseInt(textfield4.getText().toString());

        if (ckb1.getState()){
            int res=((a+b)*70+(c+b)*80)+30;
            textfield5.setText(String.valueOf(res));
        }
        else {
            int res=((a+b)*70+(c+b)*80);
        textfield5.setText(String.valueOf(res));
        }
            }


}
```

you were concatinating final answer i.e delivery charge
 for sample i have attached the output [image: Concatinating answer image]

and i have modified the code and find the screenshot for modified code
[image: Changed output image]

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't lie.  [In AWT there is no isSelected() method for CheckBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html)

You're looking for `ckb1.getState()`

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html

looking at the API, it seems the Checkbox object doesn't have an isSelected method. Perhaps what you are looking for is getState(). It determines if the checkbox is in the on or off state.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
ckb1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getState()) {//checkbox has been selected
        //do something...
    } else {//checkbox has been deselected
        //do something...
    };
}
```

});

you first need to add the item listener and then get the state

getState() will return a boolean value and you can use the if-else to do your job :)

Answer (score 0):

`Swing` and `AWT` checkboxes are not the same, while `JCheckBox` does actually have `isSelected()` method, the `AWT` counterpart does not.

Anyway, I'd suggest to use event for state change tracking instead of accessing an `UI` component directly, e.g.:

```
checkbox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        System.out.printf("%s\n", e.getStateChange() == 1 ? "checked" : "unchecked");
    }
});
```